# GoogeDrive API - how to get permissions data from file

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to get the permission data for the files in GoogleDrive.
To get the files I'm using the following code:

```
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(config['credentials-file'],
                                                                        scopes=config['resource-scopes'])
        self._drive_service = discovery.build(serviceName='drive',
                                              version='v3',
                                              credentials=credentials,
                                              cache_discovery=False)

        self._drives = self._drive_service.drives().list().execute()['drives']
        files_list = self._service_v3.files().list(corpora='drive',
                                                   supportsAllDrives=True,
                                                   includeItemsFromAllDrives=True,
                                                   driveId=self._drives[0]['id'],
                                                   spaces='drive',
                                                   fields='*').execute()
```

After executing this code, I get a list of files that looks like this:

```
files[0] = {'id': 'file_id', 'permissionIDs' : ['permissionId1', 'permissionId1', ...], ...}
```

But when I'm trying to get the permission data as specified in GoogleDriveApi I get an error:

```
self._service_v3.permissions().get(fileId='file_id', permissionId='permissionId1').execute()
```

> *** googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/file_id/permissions/permissionId1?alt=json returned "File not found: file_id."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issues using by using `v2` Api version and `supportsAllDrives=True` flag:

```
self._service_v2 = build(serviceName='drive',
                                 version='v2',
                                 credentials=credentials)
permission = self._service_v2.permissions().get(fileId='file_id', permissionId='permissionId1', supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
```